# Using AutoMapper and Entity Framework to change what columns are fetched from a database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper, iqueryable, automapper-8

We have a new requirement where we need to dynamically fetch a list of columns from a table. We have 141 columns in this table, but say we only want to return 2 or 3 of them, we just don't know which 3 until run-time.

These columns are passed in as a `List<string>`, with the hopes I could use reflection to access the property on the source object.

We have support for this already by being able to pass a `TObjectDto` into our service which our `IQueryable` is projected to before hitting the database, it just doesn't handle the dynamic columns part of the equation.

So far I have unable to do something similar using MapFrom (no luck because reflection is not supported in LINQ, and it must be LINQ because otherwise it's not supported by queryable)

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

Is there any reason I should keep going down this rabbit hole and instead just use what I have to generate some raw SQL?

Comment: Seems to me your database design is wrong for this application

Comment: No disagreement from me, this is in a way the core of our application and is pretty massive (in columns and data)

Comment: You need 80~ different queries which you need to choose via a string (name of the column or whatever is best). What about something like a Dictionary<string,Func<Task<List<string>>>> ?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that I am pretty happy with

I declared a Dto class that inherits directly from my model class

```
    public class MyObjectDto : MyObject
    {
    }
```

Then configured a AutoMapper profile like so

```
CreateMap<MyObject, MyObjectDto>()
            .ForAllMembers(s => s.ExplicitExpansion());
```

I then curated the list of fields I do want to retrieve and

```
                result = await myObjects
                    .ProjectTo<TMyObjectDto>(_mapperConfiguration, null, fieldsToRetrieve.ToArray())
                    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This then only queries the database values for the properties in `fieldsToRetrieve` and leaves the rest as null/default values, perfect for what I need

Thanks to Lucian for pointing me in the right direction in the comments